Are pow(\x, n) and \x*\x*...*\x for n times exactly the same as (\x)^n (\x to the power of n) with n is a set of natural number when writing code?
I know that (\x)^n means '\x raises to the power of n', but I have just found at least two alternative ways of coding this thing, they are the following,
[pow(\x, n)] and [\x*\x*...*\x for n times].
I drop down this note after reading the answer link: Sketching an slope field in a different way
My question is do these mean '\x raises to the power of n'? If yes, then is this technique worked for all independent variable \x? In the link given in this question, I use \x=\xmin+\i*\hx.

Note that x^a is translated as exp(a*log(x)).  Not sure how pow(x,n) is able to determine that n is an integer.  I suspect that it only works for 2, 3 and 4.

BTW, the correct way to calculate a*x^2+b*x+c is (a*x+b)*x+c. Fewer flops and more accurate.

Page 1031 of the the pgf/tikz manual:

x ^ y  (infix operator; uses the pow function)
Raises x to the power y.


Unfortunately, I don't have a manual. But many thanks for pointing this thing out, @crf.

@HectorLai texdoc tikz will bring up the manual. or you can view it online if you don't have the docs installed.
